# How do I make flour and bread?

Tags: farm-and-grow

I found this game, [Farm and Grow](http://www.kongregate.com/games/CuriousGaming/farm-and-grow). I researched grain, but it's not edible so my wife and I died. I assume that you can grind it into flour and make bread. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a fair bit of testing (and the death of a few family members), I managed to figure out how to bake bread.

First, you must earn money via trading at the market, or performing labour. Once you have 25 gold, you may then send your family member to school. This will increase your Knowledge by 10.

This Knowledge can be used in various research (of which you are already aware, but I feel the need to mention it for the sake of completeness). The specific research tree you are looking for is "Infrastructure".

After spending 10, 15, and 25 (if I remember correctly) points of Knowledge, the following training should become available:

[image]

Once you have spent the 30 Knowledge to research the Bakery, you may proceed to turn flour into Bread. (It is here that I should mention the research prior to Bakery is Mill, which allows you build a windmill for grinding grain into flour)

Once you have built your windmill and harvested your grain, you may then proceed to grind the grain into flour for the purposes of bread baking.

[image]

Once you have collected your flour (it only takes 1 to make bread), simply click the diamond below your house. You should see "Bake Bread". Voila! You now have bread for consumption!

[image]